# MySQL Stored Function gives Access violation:1305 in Laravel but works in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have following stored function defined in my local database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GenerateSectionFee`(`in_month` INT, `in_year` INT, `in_section_detail_id` INT, `in_issue_date` DATE, `in_due_date` DATE) RETURNS int(11)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN    
    /** Variables declartion **/
    declare v_new_mfm_id int;


    /** insert heads of given grade & section **/
    insert into month_fees_masters(section_details_id, fee_month, fee_year, issue_date, due_date,  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9, h10, 
        th1, th2, th3, th4, th5, th6, th7, th8, th9, th10)
    select  
        class_detail_id, in_month, in_year, in_issue_date, in_due_date, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9, h10, 
        th1, th2, th3, th4, th5, th6, th7, th8, th9, th10 
    from fee_masters 
    where class_detail_id=in_section_detail_id and fee_type='R';

    /** Get id of inserted record **/
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into v_new_mfm_id;

    /** insert monthly fee of all students of given grade & section **/
    insert into month_fees(month_fees_masters_id, student_id, arears, fine_amount, fee_con, deposit_amount, status)
    select 
        v_new_mfm_id, s.id, (f.arears+f.fine_amount-f.fee_con-f.deposit_amount), 0 fine_amount, s.fee_con, 0 deposit_amount, 'L' status 
    from
        students s inner join month_fees f on s.id=f.student_id and f.status='L'
    where 
        s.cur_class_detail_id = in_section_detail_id and s.status='ACTIVE'
    ;

return (0); /** Zero means No Error. Records created successfully **/
END
```

When I call it from **phpmyadmin** it works fine. but when I call it from **Laravel** it gives following error:

```
[2014-11-03 05:53:54] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE iiui_db.GenerateSectionFee does not exist (SQL: call GenerateSectionFee(10, 2014, 27, 2014-10-01, 2014-10-08))' in C:\wamp\www\SchoolWeb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:555
```

I am calling this function from Laravel as follows:

```
$flag_ = DB::statement('call GenerateSectionFee(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', $data);
```

While $data is an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CALL` is used with stored procedures - [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/call.html), while for a function you do:

```
select function(args)
```

so in your case:

```
$flag_ = DB::statement('select GenerateSectionFee(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', $data);
```